# If $x^5-x^3 +x=a, $ show that $x^6\ge2a-1. $

Tags: polynomials

If $x^5-x^3 +x=a, $ show that $x^6\ge2a-1. $

I am unable to solve this problem.

Please help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $x$ and $a$ are arbitrary real numbers?

Comment: can you say something about the variables?

Comment: You could try to show that $x^6 -2 x^5 + 2x^3 -2x+1\ge 0$ (why the downvote?)

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @T.Bongers The question is absolutely clear and meaningful. I really don't understand this criticism.

Comment: @Thomas This site isn't a homework mill - I downvote and vote to close questions that are posed as isolated exercises without any apparent thought or effort by the asker.

Comment: @T.Bongers well, you've earned enough reputation to act as you see fit, of course. But (you may call me a nitpicker) the reason given for the current vote to close does not match any statement given in the help center. To the contrary, there it is said that a question is appropriate for this site if is a "Mathematical problem(s) such as one might come across in a course or textbook". I, btw, tend to upvote questions if I'm under the impression it got downvoted for inappropriate reasons ;-)

Comment: @Thomas This has been discussed on meta *many* times before. Regardless, my vote in this case is at least partially based on the fact that the asker here has posted *many* problems exactly like this - no thought or effort, just wanting someone to do it for them.

Comment: @T.Bongers I see. Pity. Unless I see the necessity to upvote because of the reason I gave in my last comment I tend to focus on the question, not on the side conditions. When I saw this question the first time I was surprised for some seconds, and the comments of 6005 and Sonnhard Graubner show there is some reason to be surprised. Still it contains every information necessary to answer it. Rather then wanting ot get rid of stuff of people because someone thinks their behaviour is incorrect I value this site because of interesting items. Maybe this changes with age.

Comment: using my favorite method add and minus $x^4,x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=x^5-x^3+x$ is an increasing function since its derivative is $5x^4-3x^2+1\geq\frac{11}{20}$.

As suggested by Thomas, it is enough to show that
$$ x^6-2x^5+2x^3-2x+1\geq 0 $$
but that is trivial, since it is equivalent to:
$$ (x-1)^2 \frac{1+x^6}{1+x^2} \geq 0.$$